# Assigning weights by group in R

Tags: r, exponential

I have a data frame

```
a  <- seq(1, 1010, 1)
b  <- seq(2,1011,1)
c  <- c(rep(1,253), rep(2, 252), rep(3,254), rep(4,251))
d  <- c(rep(5,253), rep(6, 252), rep(7,254), rep(8,251))
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
```

I want to group my sample by column c and d and assign for each first 250 observations with weights which declines exponentially i.e. first observation of group for instance with 0.06*(0.94)^250, second observation with 0.06*(0.94)^249, third 0.06*(0.94)^248 ..... and the last observation of the group (i.e. row 250) with 0.06*0.94^0.

It is quite simple to do it with for loop but as I have a huge data frame possibly you know any function which can do faster.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [codereview.SE], since it is about Code Review and improvement. Your code works well and you try to just find a faster way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `dplyr` approach:

```
require(dplyr)

df <- df %.%
  group_by(c,d) %.%
  filter(1:n() <= 250) %.%
  mutate(weight = 0.06*(0.94)^(seq(249,0,-1)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I ticked this as an answer because run very quickly.

Comment: @user3618375 welcome! I just made a slight simplification - no need to calculate `m` and remove it later on.

Comment: Curious, why does it give me a unary operator error on the last line (complaining about the `-n`)?

Comment: @Joe i just corrected it. `n` is of course a column name and hence cannot be directly accessed in that way as I wrote it. In my original solution I had it inside a `c()` and when i updated it, i made a little mistake there. Now it should work.

Comment: I don't think you need the n at all, I'll make an edit and if you don't agree reverse it - but it looks like it works for me.

Comment: For that matter the `249-seq` can be changed to `seq(249,0,-1)` of course, I was just following the structure of your code and not thinking.

Comment: @Joe very nice indeed. You can make another edit if you like :)

Comment: It just matter of converting 'df' to data frame , then it works )

Comment: if you need a "normal" data.frame as output, you can just add after the `mutate`: `%.% as.data.frame()`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any built-in function to do this directly. Thus, I would approach this as follows:

```
df$weights <- NA_real_ # # a new column
sapply(split(1:nrow(df), paste(df$c, df$d)), function(i) {
   df$weights[i[1:251]] <<- 0.06*0.94^(250:0)
})
```

First, we split the data frame into groups corresponding to c&d. Importantly, for each group we just want to obtain the row numbers, `i`, that belong to it. Then we calculate the weights for the first 251 elements. Some simple tweaks may be applied so that this solution works if the number of elements in each group is smaller of larger than 251.